# Python - Google Calendar API - Service Account - No List of Events

Tags: python, calendar, google-api, service-accounts

For weeks I've been trying to get my Google Calendar events to work from a Python script on the terminal.  My goal is to pull my events from a specific time (yesterday), change the name of the event, and save them with the new name.

I've read many Stack Overflow pages and a good chunk of the API documentation, and even asked my Python teacher (I'm taking a night class), without any luck.

The following code "works" and produces a bunch of stuff, including a list of "items" that is empty [].  I suspect that I'm not actually connected to my calendar since the list in theory should be full of all of my stuff; that or I'm way more off than I ever imagined.

Anyways, this is the code I have that produces the undesired result in two ways. Thank you in advance for any help!

```
import pprint
import pytz
import httplib2
import requests

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

with open('calendarchecker.p12', 'rb') as f:
  key = f.read()

service_account_name = #EMAIL ADDRESS IN OAUTH SERVICE ACCOUNT

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
service_account_name, key, 
scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'])

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http)

showDeleted = True

lists = service.calendarList().list().execute()
pprint.pprint(lists)

page_token = None
while True:
  events = service.events().list(calendarId=service_account_name, pageToken=page_token).execute()
  pprint.pprint(events)
  for event in events['items']:
    print event['summary']
  page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
  if not page_token:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    service_account_name,
    key, 
    scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'],
    sub='<userid to impersonate>')
```

If you have delegated domain-wide access to the service account and you want to impersonate a user account, specify the email address of the user account in the sub parameter when you create the Credentials object. For example:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key,
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin',
    sub='user@example.org')
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)